# Is there some cloud solutions to train model in Python and than import result in GBQ?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, auto

I load a data from GBQ in Jupiter Notebook with pd.read_gbq(). Then I preprocess them and do ML model (I know about BigQueryML, but that's not enough for my tasks). I know how to load results in GBQ, but I dont know how to make it automatically. I need train model and predict every day. Is there some opportunities with cloud services? Maybe with using Colab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Google Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/), is a service that allows users to manage workflow orchestration that let you schedule and monitor pipelines, is built on Apache Airflow, you can write complex workflows using Python.

Composer use [DAG's](http://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html)(Directed acyclic graph), every vertex of a DAG represents one task and the edges represent the direction to the next task.

So you can schedule a DAG to load data from BigQuery, train your ML Model and then load the results to BigQuery.

I give you a guide on how to write a [DAG with python](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/writing-dags), the Python Operator also has the packages to interact with BigQuery or Tensoflow.

Answer (score 0):

With [Google AI Platform](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/) you can train and ask for predictions entirely online. You can use models created with Tensorflow, scikit-learn or XGBoost and have predictions both batch (only Tensorflow) and online. You can also create, storage and question different versions of the same model.